# Prove $\gcd (2^n- 1 ;2^m-1) = (2^d-1)$

Tags: arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

Looking for a high school level proof of
$\gcd (2^n-1 ; 2^m-1)=(2^d-1)$
Where $d= \gcd(m;n)$

Comment: If you tell us how you got started and where you are stuck perhaps we can help.

Comment: When writing TeX you need to put the dollars around the whole formula. Just putting them about each separate symbol (i) makes more work for yourself, and (ii) makes the spacing come out wrong.

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint:}$Use euclidean algorithm.Denote by $(a,b)$ as the gcd of $a,b$

Observe::$\quad\begin{align}(2^m-1,2^n-1)&=(2^m-1,2^n-1-2^m+1)\\&=(2^m-1,2^m*(2^{n-m}-1))\\&=(2^m-1,2^{(n-m)}-1)\end{align}$  (Assume WLOG $n>m$).

This is similar to, $(m,n)=(m-n,n)$ in the method of finding gcd using the euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $d=(m,n)$ and $p=(2^n-1,2^m-1)$ so that $p | (2^n-1)$ & $p | (2^m-1)$ since $p$ is their GCD.
Now since p divides both of them we can write ,
$$ 2^n \equiv 1 (\text{mod }p )$$
$$ 2^m \equiv 1 (\text{mod }p )$$
Due to Bezout's lemma since $(m,n)=d$ there must exist integers $x,y$ such that $mx+ny=d$ .
Using the congruences and raising them to suitable powers and multiplying we conclude ,
$$ \displaystyle 2^{mx+ny}\equiv 1 (\text{mod }p)$$
This proves that $p | 2^d-1$ which gives $p\le (2^d-1)$ . Now since $d |m$ and $d|n$ we can prove that $2^d-1 | 2^m-1$ and $2^d-1 | 2^n-1$ .
But then $(2^d-1)$ is a common divisor of both $(2^m-1)$ and $(2^n-1)$ and it must be less than or equal to the GCD i.e. $2^d-1\le p$ as the GCD is the greatest common divisor.

Thus we conclude that $p=2^d-1$ from the condition $2^d-1\le p \le 2^d-1$ .

Note : If $m|n$ then $2^n-1=2^{mk}-1=(2^m)^k-1=(2^m-1)(...)$ and thus $2^m-1 | 2^n-1$